# Finding and deleting columns which contain a certain string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data file that contains URL links in certain columns.
Eg: The 'photo' column has values as a link:
https://cdn.sofifa.org/players/4/19/193080.png

Similarly, other columns have links like these also. I want to find all the columns which contain links and drop them.

I've tried using this code:

```
fb.str.contains('https') # fb = My DataFrame
```

but it shows the following error :

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Comment: Hey Erfan, welcome to stackoverflow, before proceeding have a look at [ask] and [mcve] unless you show us your sample input (as a raw textual format) and output it will be difficult to help. You know your data and problem but no one else does, raw data helps contextualise your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`.str` is part of `pd.Series`, not `pd.DataFrame`. You can check each column with `.apply` and filter down to just the columns that don't have https in them:

```
In [91]: df
Out[91]:
   a      b  c
0  1  https  4
1  2         5
2  3         6

In [92]: df.loc[:, df.apply(lambda x: ~x.astype(str).str.contains('https').any())]
Out[92]:
   a  c
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Comment: What does the .any() function do?

Comment: It collapses a row or column of boolean `True`/`False` values into a single value of `True` if any of the elements are true. There's also `.all()` that requires all elements to be `True`

Answer (score 0):

`.str` needs to be used on a specific dataframe column or series that contains strings, not the entire dataframe. Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'site': ['https//www.google.com', 'https://www.facebook.com', 'Reddit', 'Youtube'],
    'monthly_visitors': np.random.randint(1000, 10000, 4)
})

# the '~' symbol means to get everything that DOESN'T meet the given condition
df.loc[~df['site'].str.contains('https'), :]
# line above should exclude site names that contains 'https'
```